# executing perl/python/... scripts using exec()

Tags: c++, linux, exec

I've been playing with the linux exec() functions in my C++ program and I'm trying to execute scripts (perl, python, php, ...).

from bash I can execute for example: sh -c "perl /home/ignition/test.pl"

but

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "\"perl /home/ignition/test.pl\"", NULL);
```

does not work. This does work:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/home/ignition/test.pl", NULL);
```

but this relies on the right path for the perl interpreter being specified as the first line of the script, which isn't very generic, for example this doesn't work with php scripts. I would like to use the sh -c method so the path for the interpreter is resolved automatically...

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try it without the extra quotes?

Comment: I thought I had tried that but I guess I didn't. It is working now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you were trying to execute a program called `"perl`, providing a file `/home/ignition/test.pl"` as the first argument. When you use the shell directly it removes the quotes before starting the program.

Try this: `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "perl /home/ignition/test.pl", NULL);`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use quotes around arguments that contain spaces when using the `exec` functions. Try:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "perl /home/ignition/test.pl", NULL);
```

Alternately, you can change the shebang line in the script from something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
```

The `env` program knows how to search the `PATH` to find the `perl` binary and doesn't rely on a hard coded location (you can be almost certain that `/usr/bin/env` exists).